# How does Priority Queue in RabbitMQ works?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, priority-queue

I want to implement 3 queues Q1, Q2 and Q3 with different priorities. Q1 > Q2 > Q3 for priority. I am expecting that if I add 5 objects in Q3 and while processing them if new object is added to Q1 then instead of picking next item from Q3 it should pick up item in Q1. Does RabbitMQ support such behavior ? Can you give some pointer about how to implement this ?

Comment: What about official RabbitMQ doc [Priority Queue Support](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html)? Does it help you?

Comment: You don't need three queues. Make one priority queue, and attach priority to each message.